# does -cp get honoured when we run a executable jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, executable-jar

I have a executable jar its *MANIFEST.MF* has `CLASS-PATH`

Now my question is will `abc.jar` be added to the *classpath* when i try to run

```
java -cp "abc.jar" -jar <executable.jar>
```

or only `CLASS-PATH` defined in *MANIFEST.MF* will be used ?

Answer (score 0):

*-cp* and *-jar* cannot be combined - you can use just one of them

Comment: do you have documentation link

Comment: this can be a comment

Comment: can find anything in the documentation that restricts me from doing that and it seem to be working for me.

Answer (score -1):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html
"By using the Class-Path header in the manifest, you can avoid having to specify a long -classpath flag when invoking Java to run the your application."

Comment: but can they be used together